# JSON conversion issue when returning data from Firebase using angular

Tags: angularjs, json

I am retrieving data from Firebase and when I convert to JSON like this:

```
$scope.array.push(angular.toJson(obj));
```

I get this:

```
["{ "lat": "50", "lon": "3", "title": "my title", "content": "my content" }"]
```

How do I convert it so that I get this:

```
[{ "lat": "50", "lon": "3", "title": "my title", "content": "my content"}]
```

In my angular directive I see the data when I `console.log` it and it appears like this:

```
[]
  0: "{ "lat": "50", "lon": "3", "title": "my title", "content": "my content" }"
```

In order to get the data from Firebase, if I do `$scope.array.push(obj);` I get this:

`[]
    0 {key : "value"}`

So in order to get my code to run I need the 'key' in quotes too.

The other issue I'm having is that the `link` function in my directive is running before the data is returned in the `scope.arrLocations` variable.  There is a `watch` that I expected to pick up changes to this variable.  So I was expecting that when I got the data formatted properly it would just work.

Here's my code in full:

```
app.factory('map', ['$q', function($q){

    var map={};
    var mapInfoItems=[];

    map.getMapInfo = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var mapitems = firebase.database().ref('mapinfo/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
        mapitems.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
            mapInfoItems.push(snapshot.val());
            deferred.resolve(mapInfoItems);
        });

        //return mapInfoItems;
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return map;

}]);



app.controller('mapController', ['$scope', 'map', function($scope, map){
        $scope.myLocations = {};
        $scope.arrLocations = [];
        var allLocations = [];
        //$scope.arrLocations = [ { "lat": "50", "lon": "3", "title": "my title", "content": "my content" }];
        $scope.mapLocations = map.getMapInfo();

        map.getMapInfo().then(function(locations){

           for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
                // create new object each iteration
                var obj ={
                   title  : locations[i].name,
                   content: locations[i].message,
                    lat   : locations[i].lat,
                    lon   : locations[i].lon
                }     
                allLocations.push(obj);
            }  

          $scope.arrLocations = allLocations;  
        });     
}]);




app.directive('myMap', [function() {

    // directive link function
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        //console.log(scope.myLocations);
        console.log('in the link function');

        //the line below works and the marker is shown on the map
        //scope.arrLocations =  [ { "lat": "50", "lon": "3", "title": "my title", "content": "my content" }];
        //console.log(scope.arrLocations);

        var map, infoWindow;
        var markers = [];
        //var lastElement = '';
        // map config
        var mapOptions = {
           // center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 3),
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lastElement.lat, scope.lastElement.lon),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: true
        };

        // init the map
        function initMap() {
            if (map === void 0) {
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
            }
        }    

        // place a marker
        function setMarker(map, position, title, content) {
            var marker;
            var markerOptions = {
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: title,
                icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
            };

            marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
            markers.push(marker); // add marker to array
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                // close window if not undefined
                if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                    infoWindow.close();
                }
                // create new window
                var infoWindowOptions = {
                    content: content
                };
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
                 infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        scope.$watch(function() { return scope.arrLocations; }, function() {
          initMap();  
          console.log(scope.arrLocations);
          scope.lastElement = scope.arrLocations[scope.arrLocations.length - 1];
          // clear markers
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
          markers = [];

          angular.forEach(scope.arrLocations, function(value, key){
            //console.log('value: ' + value + ' | key: ' + key);
            // a single object in this example could be:
            // { lat: 50, lon: 3, title: "my title", content: "my content" }
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon);
            setMarker(map, location, value.title, value.content);
          });


        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        //scope: {getMapFn: '&'},
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link

    };
}]);
```

Comment: what to you want to do?

Comment: not familiar with angular, but the way I see the code, you are pushing the JSON object into the array `$scope.array.push` so it is referenced as the the object in first position of the array to access it. `$scope.t = array[0];` and before that _parse_ the JSON.

Comment: I want an array of objects like this, the rest of my code should fine work after I get it in this format `[{"a" : "b"}]`

Comment: @SaugatSingh `push()` does not add to beginning of an array

Answer (score 0):

Don't stringify the object...just push the object itself to array

Change:

```
$scope.array.push(angular.toJson(obj));
```

To

```
$scope.array.push(obj);
```

As for the console log of length it sounds like you are trying to check length before data has been pushed into the array. Most likely before the data request has been received

Comment: I think the issue might be more complex.  I'll have a think about it and update the post when I know more.

Comment: I've added in some more detail.  Yes checking the length before the data has been pushed to the array is part of the problem.  The link function is being called before the data has been received.

Comment: suggest you use an angular maps module, there are several of them around

Comment: Ok cheers, might persevere for a bit longer - I'm so close! :)

Comment: Took your advice and used  an angular maps module.  If you want to update your answer to show the module I used I'll happily accept your answer.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: that really doesn't answer the actual question asked...just simplifies your project quite a bit and means you don't have to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct.  Might be better deleting this one.  I couldn't find any solution to it :(

Answer (score 0):

Gave up using my existing code.  Decided to use [this](http://ngmap.github.io/#/infowindow_ng_click.html) instead.